# How to change the focus from edittext view

Tags: android, focus

I have a one textview two edittext fields. am using first for the taking input text from user .

for the  Second view I made the focusable set to false and I wrote a onClickListener which pops up(Date Picker) so that user can set the date.

Scenario:

I first I click on the first edit text and I start typing some text when am done I click on the second edittext and a I get a popup(Dialog) I select the date and click set on the dialog.

My Problem here is : After setting the Date, focus is still in the first field.

What I have tried.

-- While implementing the onClickListener for the second edittext , I tried to change the focus to the textView.

```
         textview.requestFocus();
```

but it din't work.

Is there a way I can change it ?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to enter date manually.. than make that Edittext to Enable false.

```
 editText.setEnabled(false);
 editText.setFocusable(false);
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

and just set the text on edittext from datepicker dialog..

Comment: can u please explain what happens if I do that?

Comment: Keyboard IME will not open for that edittext.. just datepicker dialog and you can set text in edittext.

Comment: am not getting the Keyboard.. my problem is am seeing the cursor position in edittext fields.. I dont want to see that...

Comment: I already have the setFocusable false for the edittext view on which I have the datepicker dialog.

My problem is regarding the cursor position. In the first edittext view  the cursor doesnt disappear.